# Get null Value to byte

Tags: c#

I am storing image in database. it is working fine.

After that I am retrieving the image.

For that I am using byte array to get data from database as in following code.

```
byte[] pic = new byte();
pic = DBNull.Value.Equals(mRS.Fields["Img"]) ? "" : mRS.Fields["Img"].Value;
```

But it is giving error.

Can Anyone please help me for this?

Comment: What error it gives?

Comment: don't think putting an empty string into byte array is allowed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some things wrong in your code:

1- `byte[] pic = new byte[size]`

2- `""` is not a byte[] it's an empty string.

Do it like this:

```
var pic = DBNull.Value.Equals(mRS.Fields["Img"]) ? new byte[0] : mRS.Fields["Img"].Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the base object `Equals` method, instead just to a standard equality comparison:

```
pic = mRS.Fields["Img"].Value == DBNull.Value ? null : mRS.Fields["Img"].Value;
```

With `Equals`, you're checking to see if two objects are the same object under the reference, which is a different type of comparison.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think that it is possible to put `""` into an byteArray. `""` is a string different than `null`. Use the following code instead with replacing "" with null and modify the DBNull check.

```
byte[] pic = new byte()[??];
pic = (mRS.Fields["Img"] == DBNull.Value) ? null : mRS.Fields["Img"].Value;
```